# mysql mediumtext & max row size

Tags: mysql

I am confused about two conflicting statements. I read repeatedly that the max size of a row is 64KB. So, for example, what does it mean to say that a mediumtext column can be 16MB if the whole row maxes out at 64KB? (I am using InnoDB.)

I have two related questions as well.

In practice, is a mediumtext field fixed or variable length? On dump it looks variable, but is it actually, or is the db record always alloting 16MB for it?

Is there a concensus that mediumtext is as useful as any smaller relative such as varchar, or is the general wisdom that it is better to use files for text over 60KB or so?

I know these are newbie questions, but I did a fair amount of searching before coming here, and I did not find answers. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rows are not limited to 64KB, not even in any qualified way that I can think of.  If you have a link to where is says that limit, let me know.

I have collected most of the 'hard' limits in MySQL [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits).

`MEDIUMTEXT` is implemented as a 3-byte length plus zero to 16MB bytes of text.  The other `TEXT` and `BLOB` datatypes are similarly designed.  They are all "variable length", not "fixed".

In general, use the datatype that works best for the data an the application code manipulating it.

As it turns out, `LONGTEXT` and `LONGBLOB` are difficult to load directly because of a 'variable' `max_allowed_packet` which has a default of 16MB.  I'm not sure if you need to be sure that (`innodb_log_file_size` * `innodb_log_files_in_group`) > 10 * the largest `TEXT` you will have.  (I don't think I have heard of anyone having such an issue.

There is a slight advantage in declaring `VARCHARs` with a reasonable size, not the `255` that is commonly seen.  There is probably no difference between larger varchars and `TEXT`, except for what the cutoff is.

File versus text/blob...  This is a common question on the forum, usually relating to the storage of images in `BLOBs`.  There are advantages/disadvantages of either approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for a very compelte answer. Here is one of the palces taht states all rows have a 64k max size. Clearly, I am misunderstnding something. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html

Comment: Check out my Comment on that page, dated May of last year.  For InnoDB, the discussion get rather long and complex, due to the 4 flavors of `ROW_FORMAT`.  There is virtually no limit on the total size of an InnoDB row; there is a limit of 4GB per column.  If you end of with a row that is giving you trouble; we can probably advise.

Comment: I wrote a [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82669) about this.

Comment: Thank you for the help and for the bug report to improve the documentation.